# Presenting random pictures using JOptionPane icon and Math.random

Tags: java, arrays, swing, joptionpane, imageicon

I am taking a programming class, and I have to make an instrument "play".  I want to use Math.random to create a random number between either 0-9 or 0-10 and have that number correspond to a picture in an array displayed via JOptionPane icon.  My only issue is, how can I create a program that will correspond a random int to a picture and then present it using JOption Pane.  Here is what I have so far:

```
   public static String Flute(String pickYourInstrument, String instrument){
      //try to assign variables to pictures in an array
      ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("/home/james/programmingpics/A_Flute");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A Note", "A Note with Flute", 
      JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, icon);
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
           int random = 1 * (int) (Math.random() * 10);
           System.out.println(random);
      }
   }
```

I am stuck, I stopped after I realized that I didn't know how to make the ImageIcon icon into an array (I have nine other pictures to make an icon for).  Does anyone have an idea how I could create the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply create an array of ImageIcon, then the random number obtained can be used as an index to that array to get the corresponding icon. Something as simple as

```
int randomNumber = //.... get random int
ImageIcon myIcon = iconArray[randomNumber];
```

Comment: That did it, thanks.  Any ideas on how to have it scroll at, say 500 ms, instead of prompting for an ok?

Comment: @trashgod: yep, that would work well too, especially if one needs to obtain random Icons in a non-repeating fashion.